# Silverlight Client side validation

Tags: validation, xaml, entity-framework-5, silverlight-5.0

I have a particular type of validation to do. Let's say I have two entities: `tblExploitationSub(idExploitationSub, idSemaine, dateActivite)` and `tblSemaine(idSemaine, Datedebut, DateFin)`. My objective is to set a validation process to check whenever I fill the idSemaine and dateActivite whether this date is between Datedebut and DateFin.
By the way, I am using Ado.net Entity Data Madel that generate the `xxxx.web.g.cs` file. And I create a new class that I want to use to modify the property `dateActivite` as below:

```
namespace appGestMO.Web.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe d'entité « tblExploitationSub ».
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class tblExploitationSub : Entity
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtient ou définit la valeur « DateActivite ».
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime DateActiviteValidation
        {
            get
            {
                return this._dateActivite;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._dateActivite != value))
                {
                    if ((this._tblSemaine == null))
                    {
                        this._tblSemaine = new EntityRef<tblSemaine>(this, "tblSemaine", this.FiltertblSemaine);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(this._tblSemaine.Entity.ToString());
                    if ((value < this.tblSemaine.DateDebut.Value) || (value > this.tblSemaine.DateFin.Value))
                    {
                        throw new ValidationException("Date Incorrecte!!!");
                    }
                    this.OnDateActiviteChanging(value);
                    this.RaiseDataMemberChanging("DateActivite");
                    this.ValidateProperty("DateActivite", value);
                    this._dateActivite = value;
                    this.RaiseDataMemberChanged("DateActivite");
                    this.OnDateActiviteChanged();
                }
            }
        }


    }    
}
```

But I am getting error. Someone may have a better solution.
Thanks...

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this.tblSemaine.DateDebut and this.tblSemaine.DateFin are nullable. Are you sure they are not null when you get to the line that is checking the date range?  this.tblSemaine.DateDebut.Value will throw a NullReferenceException if this.tblSemaine.DateDebut is null.